# Chrome strange behaviour on definition checking: ReferenceError: x is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm wondering this strange behavior of chrome from it's last update. When I want to check if a variable is defined it throws an uncaught error as below:

```
if(x) { alert('x is defined.'); }
```

And this line throws:

```
ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

I know how to handle this but from my previous experience this should return undefined not throwing an exception in my application.
Why this is happening? I think it should check to see if x is a property of window object or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're using `x` somewhere else without initializing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between a variable not being declared, and the variable being declared but having an undefined value. The alert comes only when you try to access a variable that hasn't been declared. You should always declare your variables, even if you're not initializing them, e.g.

```
var x;
if (x) {
    alert('x is defined');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/CC6K8/1/)

Comment: I thought it should look for the object as a property of window object. I know what you say.

Comment: I mean it should interpret the line as 'if(window.x){}'

Comment: If that's how you want it to interpret it, write that. I think Google is trying to be helpful in detecting variable name typos.

Comment: Assume this: "u =12";then "window.u" will be 12. and "window.x" returns undefined. but "x" throws exception.

Comment: This is not new. I found a blog post from 2008 saying that accessing an undeclared variable is a runtime error: http://constc.blogspot.com/2008/07/undeclared-undefined-null-in-javascript.html. If Chrome wasn't reporting the error before, it was a bug, and they've now fixed it.